# using ajax url to call php file

Tags: php, ajax, path

Cant seem to connect the ajax url to a php file. I've been fiddling around for ages.

File path of JavaScript: h******ze.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/buddyboss-theme-child/assets/js

needs to be be linked to file path PHP:

h******ze.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/buddyboss-platform/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/buddypress/activity/user-duration.php

```
setInterval(function(){ 

$.ajax({
  url: '/public_html/wp-content/plugins/buddyboss-platform/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/buddypress/activity/user-duration.php',
    

  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
  }
});

}, 3000);
```

Comment: Do you actually use the `public_html` prefix in your URLs? That seems like a local filesystem path to the web root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the website is visible at h???????ze.com and not h??????ze.com/public_html your URL should be /wp-content/plugins/buddyboss-platform/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/buddypress/activity/user-duration.php

public_html is the root of your website and will contain index.php so you need to point it there. The browser has no access to anything before this in the URL you are using.